# Jquery Toggle Questions

Tags: jquery, toggle

I am having some trouble getting a series of links and correspoding divs to hide and show. Basically a tabbed navigation.

```js
$('#toShow>div>div>div:gt(0)').hide(); // hide all but first

$('#links .dslc-button').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#toShow>div>div>div:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').show(1700).siblings('div').stop(1).hide(1700);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dslc-main">
  <div id="links" class="dslc-modules-section " style="">
    <div class="dslc-modules-section-wrapper dslc-clearfix">
      <div class="dslc-modules-area dslc-col dslc-2-col dslc-first-col" data-size="2">
        <div id="dslc-module-355" class="dslc-module-front dslc-module-DSLC_Button dslc-in-viewport-check dslc-in-viewport-anim-none  dslc-col dslc-12-col dslc-last-col  dslc-module-handle-like-regular  dslc-in-viewport" data-module-id="355" data-dslc-module-id="DSLC_Button"
        data-dslc-module-size="12" data-dslc-anim="none" data-dslc-anim-delay="0" data-dslc-anim-duration="650" data-dslc-anim-easing="ease" data-dslc-preset="none" style="animation: forwards 0.65s ease none;">
          <div class="dslc-button">
            <a href="#" target="_self" onclick="" class="">
              <span class="dslc-icon dslc-icon-link"></span>
              <span class="dslca-editable-content" data-id="button_text" data-type="simple">CLICK TO EDIT</span>
            </a>
          </div>
          <!-- .dslc-button -->
        </div>
        <!-- .dslc-module -->
      </div>
      <div class="dslc-modules-area dslc-col dslc-2-col " data-size="2">
        <div id="dslc-module-356" class="dslc-module-front dslc-module-DSLC_Button dslc-in-viewport-check dslc-in-viewport-anim-none  dslc-col dslc-12-col dslc-last-col  dslc-module-handle-like-regular  dslc-in-viewport" data-module-id="356" data-dslc-module-id="DSLC_Button"
        data-dslc-module-size="12" data-dslc-anim="none" data-dslc-anim-delay="0" data-dslc-anim-duration="650" data-dslc-anim-easing="ease" data-dslc-preset="none" style="animation: forwards 0.65s ease none;">
          <div class="dslc-button">
            <a href="#" target="_self" onclick="" class="">
              <span class="dslc-icon dslc-icon-link"></span>
              <span class="dslca-editable-content" data-id="button_text" data-type="simple">CLICK TO EDIT</span>
            </a>
          </div>
          <!-- .dslc-button -->
        </div>
        <!-- .dslc-module -->
      </div>
      <div class="dslc-modules-area dslc-col dslc-2-col " data-size="2">
        <div id="dslc-module-357" class="dslc-module-front dslc-module-DSLC_Button dslc-in-viewport-check dslc-in-viewport-anim-none  dslc-col dslc-12-col dslc-last-col  dslc-module-handle-like-regular  dslc-in-viewport" data-module-id="357" data-dslc-module-id="DSLC_Button"
        data-dslc-module-size="12" data-dslc-anim="none" data-dslc-anim-delay="0" data-dslc-anim-duration="650" data-dslc-anim-easing="ease" data-dslc-preset="none" style="animation: forwards 0.65s ease none;">
          <div class="dslc-button">
            <a href="#" target="_self" onclick="" class="">
              <span class="dslc-icon dslc-icon-link"></span>
              <span class="dslca-editable-content" data-id="button_text" data-type="simple">CLICK TO EDIT</span>
            </a>
          </div>
          <!-- .dslc-button -->
        </div>
        <!-- .dslc-module -->
      </div>
      <div class="dslc-modules-area dslc-col dslc-2-col " data-size="2">
        <div id="dslc-module-358" class="dslc-module-front dslc-module-DSLC_Button dslc-in-viewport-check dslc-in-viewport-anim-none  dslc-col dslc-12-col dslc-last-col  dslc-module-handle-like-regular  dslc-in-viewport" data-module-id="358" data-dslc-module-id="DSLC_Button"
        data-dslc-module-size="12" data-dslc-anim="none" data-dslc-anim-delay="0" data-dslc-anim-duration="650" data-dslc-anim-easing="ease" data-dslc-preset="none" style="animation: forwards 0.65s ease none;">
          <div class="dslc-button">
            <a href="#" target="_self" onclick="" class="">
              <span class="dslc-icon dslc-icon-link"></span>
              <span class="dslca-editable-content" data-id="button_text" data-type="simple">CLICK TO EDIT</span>
            </a>
          </div>
          <!-- .dslc-button -->
        </div>
        <!-- .dslc-module -->
      </div>
      <div class="dslc-modules-area dslc-col dslc-2-col " data-size="2">
        <div id="dslc-module-359" class="dslc-module-front dslc-module-DSLC_Button dslc-in-viewport-check dslc-in-viewport-anim-none  dslc-col dslc-12-col dslc-last-col  dslc-module-handle-like-regular  dslc-in-viewport" data-module-id="359" data-dslc-module-id="DSLC_Button"
        data-dslc-module-size="12" data-dslc-anim="none" data-dslc-anim-delay="0" data-dslc-anim-duration="650" data-dslc-anim-easing="ease" data-dslc-preset="none" style="animation: forwards 0.65s ease none;">
          <div class="dslc-button">
            <a href="#" target="_self" onclick="" class="">
              <span class="dslc-icon dslc-icon-link"></span>
              <span class="dslca-editable-content" data-id="button_text" data-type="simple">CLICK TO EDIT</span>
            </a>
          </div>
          <!-- .dslc-button -->
        </div>
        <!-- .dslc-module -->
      </div>
      <div class="dslc-modules-area dslc-col dslc-2-col dslc-last-col" data-size="2">
        <div id="dslc-module-360" class="dslc-module-front dslc-module-DSLC_Button dslc-in-viewport-check dslc-in-viewport-anim-none  dslc-col dslc-12-col dslc-last-col  dslc-module-handle-like-regular  dslc-in-viewport" data-module-id="360" data-dslc-module-id="DSLC_Button"
        data-dslc-module-size="12" data-dslc-anim="none" data-dslc-anim-delay="0" data-dslc-anim-duration="650" data-dslc-anim-easing="ease" data-dslc-preset="none" style="animation: forwards 0.65s ease none;">
          <div class="dslc-button">
            <a href="#" target="_self" onclick="" class="">
              <span class="dslc-icon dslc-icon-link"></span>
              <span class="dslca-editable-content" data-id="button_text" data-type="simple">CLICK TO EDIT</span>
            </a>
          </div>
          <!-- .dslc-button -->
        </div>
        <!-- .dslc-module -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="toShow" class="dslc-modules-section " style="">
    <div class="dslc-modules-section-wrapper dslc-clearfix">
      <div class="dslc-modules-area dslc-col dslc-12-col dslc-last-col" data-size="12">
        <div id="dslc-module-362" class="dslc-module-front dslc-module-DSLC_Text_Simple dslc-in-viewport-check dslc-in-viewport-anim-none  dslc-col dslc-12-col dslc-last-col  dslc-module-handle-like-regular  dslc-in-viewport" data-module-id="362" data-dslc-module-id="DSLC_Text_Simple"
        data-dslc-module-size="12" data-dslc-anim="none" data-dslc-anim-delay="0" data-dslc-anim-duration="650" data-dslc-anim-easing="ease" data-dslc-preset="none" style="animation: forwards 0.65s ease none;">
          <div class="dslc-text-module-content">
            <h1>ONE</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- .dslc-module -->
      </div>
      <div class="dslc-modules-area dslc-col dslc-12-col dslc-last-col" data-size="12">
        <div id="dslc-module-363" class="dslc-module-front dslc-module-DSLC_Text_Simple dslc-in-viewport-check dslc-in-viewport-anim-none  dslc-col dslc-12-col dslc-last-col  dslc-module-handle-like-regular  dslc-in-viewport" data-module-id="363" data-dslc-module-id="DSLC_Text_Simple"
        data-dslc-module-size="12" data-dslc-anim="none" data-dslc-anim-delay="0" data-dslc-anim-duration="650" data-dslc-anim-easing="ease" data-dslc-preset="none" style="animation: forwards 0.65s ease none;">
          <div class="dslc-text-module-content">
            <h1>TWO</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- .dslc-module -->
      </div>
      <div class="dslc-modules-area dslc-col dslc-12-col dslc-last-col" data-size="12">
        <div id="dslc-module-369" class="dslc-module-front dslc-module-DSLC_Text_Simple dslc-in-viewport-check dslc-in-viewport-anim-none  dslc-col dslc-12-col dslc-last-col  dslc-module-handle-like-regular  dslc-in-viewport" data-module-id="369" data-dslc-module-id="DSLC_Text_Simple"
        data-dslc-module-size="12" data-dslc-anim="none" data-dslc-anim-delay="0" data-dslc-anim-duration="650" data-dslc-anim-easing="ease" data-dslc-preset="none" style="animation: forwards 0.65s ease none;">
          <div class="dslc-text-module-content">
            <h1>3</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- .dslc-module -->
      </div>
      <div class="dslc-modules-area dslc-col dslc-12-col dslc-last-col" data-size="12">
        <div id="dslc-module-370" class="dslc-module-front dslc-module-DSLC_Text_Simple dslc-in-viewport-check dslc-in-viewport-anim-none  dslc-col dslc-12-col dslc-last-col  dslc-module-handle-like-regular " data-module-id="370" data-dslc-module-id="DSLC_Text_Simple"
        data-dslc-module-size="12" data-dslc-anim="none" data-dslc-anim-delay="0" data-dslc-anim-duration="650" data-dslc-anim-easing="ease" data-dslc-preset="none">
          <div class="dslc-text-module-content">
            <h1>4</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- .dslc-module -->
      </div>
      <div class="dslc-modules-area dslc-col dslc-12-col dslc-last-col" data-size="12">
        <div id="dslc-module-371" class="dslc-module-front dslc-module-DSLC_Text_Simple dslc-in-viewport-check dslc-in-viewport-anim-none  dslc-col dslc-12-col dslc-last-col  dslc-module-handle-like-regular " data-module-id="371" data-dslc-module-id="DSLC_Text_Simple"
        data-dslc-module-size="12" data-dslc-anim="none" data-dslc-anim-delay="0" data-dslc-anim-duration="650" data-dslc-anim-easing="ease" data-dslc-preset="none">
          <div class="dslc-text-module-content">
            <h1>5</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- .dslc-module -->
      </div>
      <div class="dslc-modules-area dslc-col dslc-12-col dslc-last-col" data-size="12">
        <div id="dslc-module-372" class="dslc-module-front dslc-module-DSLC_Text_Simple dslc-in-viewport-check dslc-in-viewport-anim-none  dslc-col dslc-12-col dslc-last-col  dslc-module-handle-like-regular " data-module-id="372" data-dslc-module-id="DSLC_Text_Simple"
        data-dslc-module-size="12" data-dslc-anim="none" data-dslc-anim-delay="0" data-dslc-anim-duration="650" data-dslc-anim-easing="ease" data-dslc-preset="none">
          <div class="dslc-text-module-content">
            <h1>SIX</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- .dslc-module -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the corresponding divs to hide and show but not sure what I am  doing wrong. I can get the initial content div to hide, one selects the different button the corresponding divs done hide and show. Is it mainly because of how I am trying to access the nested divs?

Here is the codepen: 
http://codepen.io/_Dawood/pen/eJqvbB

Answer (score 0):

I think this works, any input is appreciated

```
$( "#links .dslc-modules-area" ).click(function() {
  var identify=$(this).index();
console.log(identify);
    $("#toShow>div>div>div").hide(600);

  $("#toShow>div>div>div").eq([identify]).toggle(600);
});
```